# Как писать "бонус-код"?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

Ставить ли между ними знак "-"? Посмотрела источники, кто как пишет, но правила найти не могу.

Answer (score 2):

Нужен **дефис**, ближайший известный аналог: "*компакт-диск*". Формально это можно подвести под одно из двух правил выбора дефисного (а не слитного) написания сложных слов:

> Сложные существительные, имеющие значение одного слова и состоящие из
>   двух самостоятельно употребляющихся существительных, соединённых без
>   помощи соединительных гласных о и е...
>   https://therules.ru/hyphen-nouns/
>
> Пишутся через дефис, как правило, сложные имена существительные без
>   соединительной гласной, обозначающие названия механизмов, термины
>   научные, технические, общественно-политические, например:
>   **вакуум-аппарат**... http://rosental-book.ru/ortho_ix.html

Вариант же *раздельного* написания отпадает потому, что заимствованное в русский слово бонус имеет грамматические признаки существительного, а не прилагательного (как "бонусный"), что ведёт к написанию в одно слово по первому правилу. Если же придавать этому элементу значение сокращённого прилагательного, то это приводит ко второму правилу (в примере "*вакуум-аппарат*" первая часть - сокращение от прилагательного "вакуумный"; то же можно сказать о "*компакт-диске*": там сокращение прилагательного "компактный").

Comment: Непонятно, почему ближайшим аналогом является компакт-диск. Здесь скорее можно выбрать слитную фору по аналогии со сложносокращенным словом.  Именно эти варианты надо различать, и именно поэтому компакт-диск  считается у Лопатина словарным.

Answer (score 2):

**Как по правилу написать бонус-код?**

Вот справочник Лопатина, **но это именно  справочник,** где очень много описательной информации.  После его длительного и внимательного прочтения можно  узнать, как пишется данное слово (если повезет) или нечто похожее на него. Этот материал **невозможно выучить и трудно систематизировать.**

**Что делать? Будем решать задачу логически.**

У нас три формы письма.

**1) Может ли слово писаться слитно?**

Только как сложносокращенное: бонусный код – бонускод. Написание неоправданное, логичнее использовать существительное ***бонус***, а не производное прилагательное ***бонусный.*** Пользователи это понимают и слитной формой практически никогда не пользуются.

**2) Может ли слово писаться раздельно?**

В текстах встречается раздельное написание (по аналогии с английским вариантом), но в русской орфографии **оно пока не утвердилось**. Поэтому такое письмо считается **ненормативным**.

**3) Методом исключения получаем дефисную форму.**

Дефисное написание является  классическим для сложного слова (или словосочетания приложение + определяемое слово), состоящего **из двух НАРИЦАТЕЛЬНЫХ  существительных** при отсутствии соединительной гласной.

Раньше у этого варианта были исключения (старик сторож), но сейчас их отменили. (Жить стало проще, жить стало веселее. Не надо анализировать позицию существительного и наличие определительного значения).

Замеченная в текстах несклоняемость сложного слова (бонус-коды, бонус-кодов) **только подтверждает уже сделанный выбор.**

**Из словаря:**

БОНУС,  [от лат. bonus - добрый, хороший]. 1. Дополнительное вознаграждение, награда; премия. Игровой б. 2. Скидка, предоставляемая продавцом в качестве награды за совершённую сделку.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **бонус-код**.

Эта тема подробно рассматривается у Лопатина:

В частности, через дефис пишутся  сочетания с приложениями, в которых **первая часть представляет собой несклоняемое существительное**, и это как раз подходит для нашего случая: **бонус-коды, активирование бонус-кода**.

Примечание

Что касается **компакт-диска**, то здесь другое правило. В русском языке (в общелитературной лексике) нет существительного ***компакт***, но есть прилагательное ***компактный.***

Компакт-диск ― это **словарное** написание, то есть форма письма рассматривается в индивидуальном порядке.

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=65#pp65

§ 121. Во всех прочих случаях (не охваченных § 119 — 120) слитное или дефисное написание существительных **регламентируется в словарном порядке.**
Далее приводятся группы существительных сходного строения, пишущихся **и через дефис, и слитно.**

1. Сложные существительные, в которых первая часть представляет собой: а) полную основу самостоятельно употребляющегося существительного, имеющего в им. п. ед. ч. окончание (ненулевое); б) усеченную основу самостоятельно употребляющегося существительного или прилагательного.

**Примеры дефисных написаний**: а) адмиралтейств-коллегия, кают-компания, мануфактур-коллегия, почт-директор, пресс-атташе, яхт-клуб; б) аудиенц-зал, зауряд-врач, **компакт-диск**, коммерц-коллегия, конференц-зал, приват-доцент, юстиц-коллегия; так же пишутся названия политических партий и направлений и их сторонников, напр.: социал-демократия, социал-демократ, национал-социализм, национал-социалист, радикал-экстремизм.

**Примеры слитных написаний:** а) вахтпарад, секстаккорд, септаккорд; б) фальшборт.

Comment: *В русском языке нет существительного компакт* — существительное есть (см. словарь Лопатина), хотя и не в этом значении.

Comment: *в которых первая часть представляет собой несклоняемое существительное, и это как раз подходит для нашего случая* — во всех словарях слово **бонус** указывается как склоняемое.

Comment: 1) Существительное "компакт" относится к узкоспециальной лексике (экономика, математика) или к  упрощенной разговорной речи (компакт вместо компакт-диск). 2) Слово "бонус" склоняется, но только не в составе сложного слова. Или вы говорите "активирование бонусов-кодов"?

Comment: 1) Я знаю (я математик). Я только хотел сказать, что такое существительное существует. 2) Здесь у Вас всё верно. Но в правиле, на которое Вы сослались в ответе, речь идёт о по-настоящему несклоняемых.

Comment: *Слово "бонус" склоняется, но только не в составе сложного слова.* Я такого правила не смог найти (в Ваших ответах тоже). В выражении "бонус-малус" многие склоняют оба слова и я не уверен, что это ошибочно (Ваши аргументы я слышал, они меня не убедили).

Comment: Не в составе ДАННОГО  сложного слова, мы же для него форму письма выбираем. У Лопатина  (если поискать) есть правило для сложных слов, в которых  не склоняется первое слово, обычно склоняемое, напр.: адрес-календарь, бизнес-класс, бой-баба, огонь-девка, генерал-майор, джаз-оркестр и др. Это § 123, п. 4. И вообще несклонямость первого слова в составе данного сложного слова всегда была важным признаком того, что слово пишется через дефис  (царь-пушка, горе-охотник, золото-старушка).

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это правило действует в какую-то другую сторону: если известно, что в словосочетании первое слово не склоняется, то нужно писать через дефис. (Не буду спорить — у Вас чувство языка лучше, просто мой формализм остаётся неудовлетворённым :)

Comment: Здесь невозможно определить, является бонус сокращённым прилагательным или же существительным, используемым в сложном слове без склонения и соединительной гласной, - по смыслу подходит и то, и другое. Код доставляет игровой бонус и является бонусным в смысле функции его доставки ("несущим бонус"). Сам он "бонусом" не является.

Comment: Так уж и невозможно. Зачем сокращать производное прилагательное, если можно использовать существительное, от которого оно образовалось. Это всем понятно, поэтому слитное написание не встречается. Так зачем Вы будете его сокращать?